# How does comparison between a string a an integer work in javascript?

Tags: javascript, compare

I just found a piece of code in which it is compared a string to an integer like this :

```
var result = "text" > 127;
```

and the result of this line of code is false. I have also tried to change it to equals or less than, and the result was still false:

```
var result = "text" === 127;
var result = "text" < 127;
```

What is the meaning to compare a string and a number like this if it always return false, or are there any cases when this will be true?

Comment: It is working based on abstract equality comparison algorithm. I have created an [opensource application](https://laraprabhu.github.io/) to explain it in detail.

Comment: Documentation has this covered. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/208/comparison-operations/2110/abstract-equality-inequality-and-type-conversion#t=201608021517406880455

Comment: @RichardHamilton I just realized it is is returning true if the string is a number just like "3" == 3

Comment: Check the difference b/w "==" and "===". You'll queries will be resolved.

Comment: Algorithm details: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3

Comment: if a string type variable say s = '3' and now if i do s == 3,  where the RHS is an integer, then it will return true, whereas if i do s === 3, then it will return false, as in the later case, it also check the **type** of both LHS and RHS.

Comment: I like this table too https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/unified/ helps show where you can get into trouble with js comparisons.

Comment: Thank you @AnkushRaghuvanshi too for pointing the way == works comparing to ===

Comment: As per my understanding when a string and number are compared , javascript converts string into a number , now a non empty string is always converted into a number that has a value `NaN` . And in Javascript whenever a number and a number having value `Nan` are compared result is always false .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compare string with number the string is converted to number, but in this case, `"text"`, the result is `NaN` (translate is Not a Number). Always result false, because an `NaN` is not a number to compare.

Verify with this:

```
var n1 = Number("text");
console.log(n1); //show NaN
```

So...

```
var result = "text" > 127;
```

Is equals

```
var result = NaN > 127; //result false always with any compare
```

But, if the text is a number can be converted

```
var result = "00999" > 127; //result true, because Number("00999") == 999
```

Comment: Thank you! this explains why the result was always false.